# STRING DATE AND TIME COMBINE AND MAKE FULL DATE TIME IN ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make date and time from the oracle select query as follows.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('230201'||''||'1529',  'YYMMDD HH24MI') , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')    FROM DUAL;
```

It returns the below result and it's OK.

`2023-02-01 15:29`

But when I try the same query with **23 or less minutes** It returns the wrong result

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('230201'||''||'1523',  'YYMMDD HH24MI') , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')    FROM DUAL;
```

`2302-01-15 23:00`

Where is the Wrong point of my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you used wrong format model. There's no space between date and time component:

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date('230201' ||''|| '1523', 'yymmddhh24mi'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') result
  2  from dual;                                          ----
                                                         here
RESULT
----------------
2023-02-01 15:23

SQL>
```

Comment: Noted with thanks .Problem Resolved